# Basic calculations and method calls in D3

Tags: d3.js

I just saw this in a power poitn, sorry couldn't copy-paste the text of the power point, So took a screen shot:

[image]

Could someone please explain how have we calculated x(0) and y(3) variables?
I am trying to learn this D3 and no success after three hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading [the D3 API documentation for linear scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear).  In short, the scale linearly maps the set domain to the set range.  Therefore, in the functions above:

- x maps the range [-1,1] to [0,640]
- y maps the range [0,1] to [0,320]

0 is halfway point of the input range [-1,1], so it will map to the halfway point of the output range [0,640] = 320; hence x(0) = 320.

3 is outside of y's input domain, but the scale will extrapolate linearly to a corresponding value outside of its domain range; hence y(3) = 960

Comment: Thanks Josh, What is the first resource you recommend to start reading D3? Their website? that D3 Book ? That D3 Tips and Tricks PDF?  D3 for Mere Mortals? ...

Comment: Generally, I would bookmark https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials.  Specifically, I found this set of tutorials by Scott Murray very helpful: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/